# Run task collection concurrently or sequentially in C#10

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a `Task` collection which must be run either concurrently or sequentially.

Concurrently:

```cs
public Task Foo(CancellationToken token)
{
  // ...
  IEnumerable<Task> tasks = GetTasks(token);
  // ...
  return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

But I'm unsure about sequentially:

```
public Task Bar(CancellationToken token)      // no `async` keyword by design
{
  // ...
  IEnumerable<Task> tasks = GetTasks(token);
  // ...

  // (1)
  return Task.Run(async () => {
    foreach (var task in tasks)
      await task.WaitAsync(token);
  }, token);

  // (2)
  return Task.Run(async () => {
    foreach (var task in tasks)
      await Task.Run(() => task, token);
  }, token);

  // (3)
  foreach (var task in tasks)
    yield return Task.Run(() => task, token);

  // (?)
}
```

Which is the safest and modern idiomatic way to do this in C#10: 1, 2 or 3? Or perhaps there's a better/safer way?

This code is run about every second, for about ten tasks - performance is not paramount, but nonetheless important. (This is run in an ASP.NET Core server application.)

UPDATE
As mentioned in the comments, the implementation of `GetTasks()` is important. Please indicate how you expect it should be implemented, so the calling code above can run the tasks sequentially.

Comment: Has `GetTasks(token);` already started all the tasks? In which case you can't stop them. It would be trivial to `await` each task in order with a `foreach` loop in an `async` method.

Comment: What does running a `Task` collection sequentially actually mean to you?

Comment: I don't believe that any of these is guaranteed to execute the tasks sequentially. `Task.Run` schedules a task to run on the thread pool, so by definition calling it in a loop will run the tasks more or less concurrent to one another.

Comment: Holding tasks in an `IEnumerable<Task>` is a bad idea as the enumerable may be regenerated each time it is run. A `Task[]` is much better.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Sorry for late response. `GetTasks()` was not under my control. I recommended to its author to change it to accommodate the answers below. Thanks.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for your comments. What do you mean by "may be regenerated each time"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends heavily on how `GetTasks` is implemented.

Let's discuss two options:

```
// Option 1:
IEnumerable<Task> GetTasks(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    foreach (var ... in ...)
       yield return Task.Run(<some sync method>);
       
    // alternatively
    foreach (var ... in ...)
       yield return <some real async method>();
}

// Option 2:
IEnumerable<Task> GetTasks(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return (from ... in ...
            select Task.Run(<some sync method>)).ToList();

    // alternatively
    return (from ... in ...
            select <some real async method>()).ToList();
}
```

In `Option 1` the caller is able to decide whether the tasks should run concurrently or sequentially because each started task is yielded sequentially.

In `Option 2` all tasks are currently running in parallel and it doesn't matter how you await them.

Let's assume `Option 1` (or something similar) is used: 
In that case you can run them in parallel by using:

```
public Task Bar(CancellationToken token)
{
    // ToList collects all Tasks without any await so all are running in parallel
    // Maybe ToList is not needed and Task.WhenAll does that for you - I'm not sure about that
    return Task.WhenAll(GetTasks(token).ToList());
}
```

Or you retrieve one task after another (sequential):

```
public async Task Bar(CancellationToken token)
{
    // This will await one task after another and so they're running sequential
    foreach (var item in GetTasks(token))
        await item;
}
```

I don't really understand why `Bar` is not `async` by design because `async` doesn't change the method signature and is completely transparent to the caller. But if needed an implementation might be:

```
public Task Bar(CancellationToken token)
{
    return Task.Run(Body);
    
    async Task Body()
    {
        // This will await one task after another and so they're running sequential
        foreach (var item in GetTasks(token))
            await item;
    }
}
```

The main difference between parallel-`Bar` and sequential-`Bar` is the exception handling. If an exception occurs in one of the task the parallel implementation will even run them all until they're finished. The sequential implementation will stop starting new tasks after the first exception occurs. This can be fixed using a `try...catch` and buffering all the tasks and raise an `AggregateException` after all tasks are finished.

According to your implementations: Please keep in mind that `WaitAsync` will only stop awaiting the task if the CancellationToken requests a stop. This will not stop the running task itself.
The same for `Task.Run`. If the CancellationToken is already set it will prevent the Task from beeing scheduled but the already running task in the context object will not be affected.
`GetTask` needs to be implemented in a way that the CancellationToken is respected.

There is no need to wrap an already running task with `Task.Run`.

**EDIT**

I searched for the source of  [`Task.WhenAll`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Task.cs,69351c6da968e5d1) and it looks that it does the parallel retrieving of all tasks for you. There is also a performance optimization if the parameter is already an array. So the shown implementation of the parallel-`Bar` should call `ToArray` instead of `ToList` or forward the `IEnumerable<Task>` without collecting all the items so `Task.WhenAll` will do this for you.

Comment: "Maybe ToList is not needed and Task.WhenAll does that for you - I'm not sure about that" - that's very simple to confirm. You should do that instead of creating confusion.

Answer (score 4):

*``` // no ``async`` keyword by design ``` is a very bad smell; and options 1 and 2 won't compile without `async`.*

---

Having

```
static async Task MethodAsync(int i) { WriteLine($"<{i}"); await Task.Delay(100); WriteLine($"{i}>"); }

static IEnumerable<Task> GetTasks()
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<5;i++ )
    {
        yield return MethodAsync(i);  
    }
}
```

we can execute and await this tasks sequentially with a `foreach`:

```
var tasks = GetTasks();

foreach (var t in tasks) // Please note it is the enumeration which starts the tasks one by one
{
    await t;
}
```

This prints

```
<0
0>
<1
1>
<2
2>
<3
3>
<4
4>
```

---

To illustrate that it's the foreach - not `await` - that starts the tasks let's use enumerators directly:

```
var tasks = GetTasks();

var enumerator = tasks.GetEnumerator();

var b = true;
while (b)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Moving to next");
  b = enumerator.MoveNext();
  Console.WriteLine("Moved");
  if(b)
  {
    await enumerator.Current;
    Console.WriteLine("After await");
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
Moving to next
<0
Moved
0>
After await
Moving to next
<1
Moved
1>
After await
Moving to next
<2
Moved
2>
After await
Moving to next
<3
Moved
3>
After await
Moving to next
<4
Moved
4>
After await
Moving to next
Moved
```

---

It's important to note that `GetTasks` is in charge here.

With the following implementation the tasks will already be started (or scheduled to start if there are a lot of them) by the time GetTasks() returns.

```
static IEnumerable<Task> GetTasks()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new ();
    for(int i=0 ; i<5;i++ )
    {
        tasks.Add(MethodAsync(i)); 
    }
    return tasks;
}
```

In this case foreach will only wait sequentially (which in not that useful).

With

```
var tasks = GetTasks();

foreach (var t in tasks) 
{
    await t;
}
```

the result will something like this:

```
<0
<1
<2
<3
<4
1>
4>
3>
0>
2>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I beg to differ :)

Comment: This doesn't answer how to sequentially execute tasks from an enumerable.

Comment: :/ I mention that if the tasks are started the code is not in control and if they are not started I show how to start and wait for them with `foreach() await t;`

Comment: Awaiting an unstarted task doesn't start the task.

Comment: @Enigmativity I rewritten my answer. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I like it. It's a good answer now.

Comment: @Enigmativity it's a good answer to a bad question. We shouldn't have to guess what the `GetTasks` is.

Comment: Sorry for late response. `GetTasks()` was not under my control, I had to work around it. Your answer helped me greatly, thank you!